# Redirect trafic from one app (workload) to other if there is prefix?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two apps (workloads): `app1` and `app2`. My goal is to redirect trafic from `app1` to `app2` if there is the `diona` prefix. For example:

```
app1/diona > app2/<api>
```

Now I have such rules:

```
rules:
  - host: host
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-37ce1ad1e8214375784d1e50805c056c
          servicePort: 80
        path: /diona
```

When I check `app1/diona` endpoint in logs of `app2` there is an error:

```
Not Found: /diona
```

How can I redirect trafic correctly without realizing `diona` prefix in `app2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using nginx ingress controller. You code will look like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: rewrite
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: ingress-37ce1ad1e8214375784d1e50805c056c
            servicePort: 80
          path: /diona
```

If you want to redirect `app1/diona/*` to `app2/*`, change annotations to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: rewrite
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: ingress-37ce1ad1e8214375784d1e50805c056c
            servicePort: 80
          path: /diona/(.*)
```

[Reference](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)